# Nativescript styling on android clip-path issues

Tags: android, ios, css, clip-path, angular2-nativescript

I am trying to use Nativescript style clip-path found [here](https://docs.nativescript.org/ui/styling). My code

```
#container {
   background-color:black;
   width:400;
   height: 250;
   background-image:url("~/testImages/test1.jpg");
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: cover; 
   -webkit-clip-path: inset(50pt 150pt 150pt 10pt);
   clip-path: inset(50pt 150pt 150pt 10pt);

   /* 
        inset(top right bottom left round top-radius right-radius bottom-radius left-radius)
   */
}
```

My view

```
<AbsoluteLayout id="container" ></AbsoluteLayout>
```

I do see the background image and all my other styles applied, but I can not get it to clip the path.

I have also tried

```
-webkit-clip-path: inset(50 150 150 10);
clip-path: inset(50 150 150 10);
```

and

```
-webkit-clip-path: inset(50% 150% 150% 10%);
clip-path: inset(50% 150% 150% 10%);
```

and

```
-webkit-clip-path: inset(50px 150px 150px 10px);
clip-path: inset(50px 150px 150px 10px);
```

My package.json file

```
{
  "name": "NativeAppTest",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "native app test",
  "nativescript": {
    "id": "com.test.native",
    "tns-ios": {
      "version": "2.1.1"
    },
    "tns-android": {
      "version": "2.2.0"
    }
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/platform-server": "2.0.0-rc.3",
    "@angular/router": "3.0.0-alpha.7",
    "email-validator": "1.0.4",
    "font-awesome": "^4.6.3",
    "nativescript-angular": "^0.3.0",
    "nativescript-social-share": "1.2.0",
    "nativescript-unit-test-runner": "^0.3.3",
    "tns-core-modules": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-traverse": "6.8.0",
    "babel-types": "6.8.1",
    "babylon": "6.8.0",
    "filewalker": "0.1.2",
    "jasmine-core": "^2.4.1",
    "karma": "^0.13.22",
    "karma-jasmine": "^1.0.2",
    "karma-nativescript-launcher": "^0.4.0",
    "lazy": "1.0.11",
    "nativescript-dev-typescript": "^0.3.2",
    "typescript": "^1.8.10"
  }
}
```

I have not tried iOS yet.
This may not be the best approach either. I am attempting to make a crop-box. In the view the user will see an image under the clip-path that they will position. I am not actually cropping the image. Any suggestions are appreciated. Thanks!

Update

Under Supported CSS properties in my link above it says

"Sets the clip-path. Supported shapes are **circle**, **ellipse**, **rect** and **polygon**. You can define your own shape using clippy".

I guess this is a different question but how do I use clippy to set up CSS property for clip-path:inset? I would do this myself but I don't know how.

Comment: This works clip-path: circle(50% at 50% 50%); This does not clip-path: inset(10% 10% 10% 10%);

Comment: This also works clip-path: polygon(5% 5%, 96% 5%, 96% 100%, 5% 100%); so clip-path: inset must not be supported or I am using it incorrectly.